# How to show httpget response on web page?

Tags: http, jsp, get

I need to show http get response from server to web page. I am using jsp pages and Apache Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: You may try `<jsp:include/>` or JSTL `<import/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to inline the result in your own HTML, use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:import>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html).

```html
<c:import url="http://example.com/some-fragment.html" />
```

But if the result is actually a whole HTML page which would cause malformed HTML when you include it inline in your own HTML, then use [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info) [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5).

```html
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```